# Шрифт для сайта, Helvetica и аналоги. Подобные шрифты для всех платформ

Tags: css, шрифты

Задача в том чтобы подобрать цепочку шрифтов для css так чтобы выглядели очень похоже на гельветику и SF Pro, содержали кирилицу, и это все работало на всех популярных системах(айос, андроид, виндовсы и линукс). Шрифты должны быть системные.

Пока что получается что-то вроде этого:

```
body {
font-family: "SF Pro", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica CY", "Nimbus Sans L", "Arial", sans-serif;
}
```

Нет мака для проверки и вообще доступа на сервер разработки из вне.
Не понятно что ставить для популярных дистрибутивов линукса?

Comment: Liberation Sans?

Comment: @andreymal это какой системы шрифт, куда его в эту цепочку сунуть?

Comment: на маке эти шрифты не сработали (High Sierra)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMpxz.png

Comment: @Victor не пойму по скрину что не сработало. По изображению шрифта мне не понятно какой это шрифт. Вы можете посмотреть какие шрифты есть в системе, может быть "Helvetica" с кирилицей? Или SF Pro по другому пишется.

Comment: Да ,в System/Library/Fonts есть Helvetica.ttc .Да ttc   ,а не ttf.Правда она с латиницей.(Судя по всему)